# Analytic continuation of a function without singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have an open set $U$ in the complex plane and a function $f$ which is analytic on all of $U$ and has no singularities at the boundary. Can such a function be necessarily continued analytically to a larger domain? If not, is there a counter example?

This question arose in my mind in connection with Landau's Lemma while I was studying about the domain of convergence of Dirichlet series and the analytic continuation of the series near the abscissa of convergence. Please tell me if you need any further details.

Comment: What do you mean when you write "and near the boundary too"?

Comment: Analytic on the boundary, yes it extends beyond the region.  But "up to" the boundary, no, for example $\sum z^n$ on $\{z : |z|<1\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I realise that the question was slightly vague and didn't exactly convey what I meant. I have made an edit.

Comment: What precisely should "has no singularities at the boundary" mean? a) For every $p \in \partial U$ there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ and a holomorphic function $F_V \colon V \to\mathbb{C}$ such that $F_V\lvert_{U\cap V} = f\lvert_{U\cap V}$? b) For every $p\in \partial U$ there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $p$, an open $W\subset U\cap V$ with $p \in \partial W$, and a holomorphic $F_V \colon V\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $F_V\lvert_W = f\lvert_W$?c) something else?

Comment: @DanielFischer The 2nd option.

Comment: If $U$ isn't required to be connected, let $U = \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, $f(z) = 1$ on the upper half-plane, and $0$ on the lower half-plane. For a connected $U$, I'm not sure, but I don't see right now how one could construct a similar situation.

Comment: Okay, that's a valid example. But yeah, I'm concerned with a connected domain, in fact, a simply connected domain that is not dense in the complex plane.